# how to validate Viewmodel in multiLang in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this viewModel and I use Asp.net MVC and EF code First .

```
 public class AddNewsVM
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TitleEn { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string BodyEn { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public Guid ImageId { get; set; }
}
```

But user can Add EnNews(englisg) Or FaNews(persian) or both of them . I don't Add Required to all them . how can I validatie it . for example I want if use enter En News Title  user should enter All En Field . do I use If statement in Action ?

Comment: You could consider a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredId]` or similar attribute (and add an additional property in the view model for the language) which would give you both client side and server side validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your needs. If you need both (client / server) validations, I recommend to use:

- https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation

If you want to just validate your ViewModel on server side (class level validation), you can write your own custom validation rules using the IValidatable.

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: I was about to answer the same thing with fluent validation. I've done it before for French and English and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can do client side validation like this

1. create one javascript validation metod.
2. perform all your custom validation, if validation fails return false at the end return true.
3. call the validation method on submit button "onclick" event

eg:- onclick="return myValidationFunction()"